# Как поместить строку в одинарные кавычки?

Tags: java, строки

Как добавить в конец строки символ " ' " не вызывая два раза  `builder.replace`?

```
String s4 = "nnnn|nnnn? nnnn dd.mm.yy|nnnn on/off";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s4);
builder.replace(0,1,"'");
```

При таком коде получаю только первую кавычку ->  `'nnn|nnnn? nnnn dd.mm.yy|nnnn on/off`

Comment: `builder.append("'")`. Что именно два раза не вызывать?

Comment: builder.replace();

Comment: Зачем нужен метод `replace`, который заменяет, если речь идёт о добавлении, что делает `append`.

Comment: `char qt = (char)39; String s4=qt + "string string"+ qt; // 'string string'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так поняла, что вам нужно всю строку поместить в одинарные кавычки. В начало строки вы смогли вставить кавычку, а вот в конец не знает как.

Если использовать StringBuilder, то это можно сделать так:

```
String s4 = "nnnn|nnnn? nnnn dd.mm.yy|nnnn on/off";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s4); // создаем StringBuilder из нашей строки
builder.insert(0, "'"); // вставляем кавычку в позицию 0
builder.append("'");   // добавляем кавычку в конец строки
```

Но можно же сделать проще в данном случае:

```
String s4 = "nnnn|nnnn? nnnn dd.mm.yy|nnnn on/off";
s4 = "'" + s4 + "'"; // склеиваем (конкантенируем) кавычку, строку, и вторую кавычку
```

А если уж прям необходимо со StringBuilder и через replace(), то лучше так:

```
String s4 = "nnnn|nnnn? nnnn dd.mm.yy|nnnn on/off";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("''"); // создаем StringBuilder из двух кавычек
builder.replace(1, 1, s4); // заменяем пустое место между кавычек на нашу строку
```

Но, опять же, правильнее через insert()

```
String s4 = "nnnn|nnnn? nnnn dd.mm.yy|nnnn on/off";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("''"); // создаем StringBuilder из двух кавычек
builder.insert(1, s4); // вставляем нашу строку в позицию 1 (между кавычек)
```